# after_commit :on => :destroy In a observer-like fashion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I want to do the following:

```
after_commit :on => :destroy do
  Advert.clean_total_active_cache
end
```

But in a observer-like fashion like this:

```
class AdvertObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_commit advert
    Advert.clean_total_active_cache
  end
end
```

It's the ":on => :destroy", that's causing me trouble, how do I specify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the record is not persisted and frozen:

```
class AdvertObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_commit advert
    if not advert.persisted? and advert.frozen?
      Advert.clean_total_active_cache
    end
  end
end
```